# Dynamic Lookup in SMS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, mobile, mobileconnect

I am trying to have a dynamic Date in my SMS, called `PaymentDueDate`. The date is in a DE, that will be the source of the journey that I am using. 
The code that I am using when building the message is:

```
%%[ 
SET @id = [_subscriberkey] 
SET @date = Lookup('payment_reminder_teste','PaymentDueDate','ContactId', @id) 
]%% 

%%=Format(@date, "MM/dd/yyyy")=%%
```

But, when I send it, it doesnt appear any Date. If I use only the `PaymentDueDate` dynamic word, the date that appears is the modifying date of the message and not the date that is in the `PaymentDueDate` field.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use mobile number string in order to retrieve data (using lookup ampscript function) from any other data extensions as shown here below. At the moment you can not use this variable _subscriberkey or any other personalization strings as _subscriberid. Into mobile connect sms you have more constraints and these strings do not work as you implement in the email template.

```
Set @mobile = MOBILE_NUMBER
```