# Dynamic Word in SMS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, date, sms

I will need to send a SMS for the first time and I will need to have on it one dynamic word, a date. I'm using AMPScript to do that but all my tentatives fail.

e.g

```
See more information on %%[
SET @id = [subscriberkey]
SET @date = Lookup("DE_NAME","FIELDNAME_I_WANT_TO_SHOW","FIELDID", @id) ]%% 
%%=FormatDate(@date, "MM DD,YYYY")=%%. To know more information contact us.
```

In my DE the field `FIELDNAME_I_WANT_TO_SHOW` is a date with the value: `07 July 2018 00:00:00`

But after I used this code inside my SMS I don´t get this date.

Comment: This question looks very similar to [Dynamic lookup in SMS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220527/dynamic-lookup-in-sms). This profile isn't registered, do you have multiple accounts to ask duplicates of your questions?

Comment: No battery.cord I don´t have multiple accounts, it seems my colleague already ask about this problem. sorry for that it is possible for you delete this? I'm sorry again.

Comment: The average user can't remove content. You should be able too, or a mod can. I've already flagged this question for moderator review, they'll see these comments and act appropriately. My advice is to register & customize your account. Without that extra step is seems a lot more like a duplicate account used to circumvent bans.

Comment: No problems, I have marked it as a duplicate.